# No internet access on TP-LINK TL-WR841ND with DD-WRT

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I'd really appreciate if you could help me out. I have no internet access on my TP-LINK TL-WR841ND v7 with DD-WRT. I installed it today and it worked flawlessly with the original tp-link firmware. I set it up, made a hard reset, plugged in everything correctly but no luck.

Another strange thing is, after a fresh reset I can't access the control panel without setting a custom IP address. Looks like DHCP isn't working by default? Disabling DNSMasq solved this problem though.

At the top of the page it shows the IP address so it can connect but I can't open webpages nor use torrent client.

I have Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14) std installed.

Here are pics about the config:

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/9pul2i1ft/ddwrt3.jpg]

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/dkxz52kll/ddwrt4.jpg]

Comment: Is it a DNS problem? Can you ping and browse Internet sites by address, but not name? Try to ping something like `8.8.8.8`. If that works, you need to fix your DNS.

Comment: @RonMaupin I can't ping anything except for the router. Pinging 8.8.8.8 resulted in timeout. Windows troubleshooter, however, says: Your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding.

Comment: Your subnet mask probably shouldn't be `255.255.255.255`. That could be your problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin I can't change it, it's determined. On the WAN tab it says 255.255.255.255 but on the LAN it's 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed 6 of these as AP's - I never got dd-wrt to work properly on this model - OpenWRT however, works flawlessly - and it's as simple as upgrading the firmware via the web interface via rj45. Direct link to the firmware for the v7

https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-15.05-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr841nd-v7-squashfs-factory.bin

Page for other revisions

https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd

They have been in for 3 years and they have worked flawlessly - as long as you set a weekly reboot.

OpenWRT takes a little getting used to - but works far better than ddwrt for this exact model that I used (tl-wr841nd V7)

Comment: The daily reboot is exactly what I wanted to avoid. That's why I decided to go for DD-WRT because it's said it's the most stable firmware. Turns out it's not. With the original FW it lost connection sometimes. Why is it necessary to reboot weekly? Are you saying that I'm doing everything well and the firmware is to blame? What problems did you encounter? Were they like mine? BTW Thanks, if I can't fix it, I'll try OpenWRT!

Comment: Every router I have known benefits from a reboot - Particularly budget Atheros based ones. Remember it's a very cheap router. It's a form of self maintenance. I always set mine for about 4am and only takes 30 seconds. 
The only 100% solid router I have used is a small PC running pfsense with intel chipset & net, and they don't wifi well so you need a separate AP.

Comment: What is the problem with a reboot on a weekly schedule? I have used cheap timer switches before on router firmware that does not have cron/reboot scheduler.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it other than I have to do it :) The thing is, I always forget about it and then sometimes it lost connection, status changed to "limited" and I have to do it. Anyway, I'd be happy with a scheduler. Does OpenWRT have a scheduler?

Comment: Yes - it's built in. Cron. Under the system menu. In the cron box type "0 3 * * * reboot" and save. This will restart router 3am each day. Cron does so much more but for now all you need to know is that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I installed OpenWRT, works flawlessly. WiFi download speeds are even faster.

Comment: Glad to help - Make sure you click the number above to say that it's the correct answer.